# Checkbox on datagridView but the appearance is button

Tags: c#

How to add Checkbox on Datagridview but the appearance of the checkbox is a button?. 
Kindly help me with this problem. Thanks

Comment: What are you targetting? Winforms?ASP?WPF?....??? Please always tag your questions accordingly!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a CheckBox to your form but styled as a button, go to the Properties window -> Appearance -> Appearance, and switch from Normal to Button.

Comment: **This is my code on placing checkbox on datagridview.** 
 <br/> <br/>
 <br/>var model = FDBContext.oFDBEntity.tMasters.Where(t => t.trGroup_c == "POSMOD").ToList();<ol/>
             <br/>model.Select(t => t.trCode_c);
             <br/>dgSecView.DataSource = model;



            <br/> <br/>dgSecView.Columns.Add(checkBox);